# Merge Sort Algorithm Assistance

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

I'm trying to implement the merge-sort algorithm. I started with pseudocode that was available in an algorithms book. The pseudocode indicates the first position in the array as 1 and not 0. I am having a very difficult time trying to implement the code.

Here is what I have. I've tried stepping through the recursion by printing out the results at each step but it is very convoluted at this point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
using size_type = std::deque<int>::size_type;
void print(std::deque<int> &v)
{
    for(const auto &ref:v)
        std::cout << ref << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
void merge(std::deque<int> &vec, size_type p, size_type q, size_type r)
{
    int n_1 = q - p;
    int n_2 = r - q;
    std::deque<int> left, right;
    for(auto i = 0; i != n_1; i++)
        left.push_back(vec[p + i]);
    for(auto j = 0; j != n_2; j++)
        right.push_back(vec[q + j]);
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    std::cout << "left = ";
    print(left);
    std::cout << "right = ";
    print(right);
    for(auto k = p; k != r; k++) {
        if((i != n_1 && j != n_2) && left[i] <= right[j]) {
            vec[k] = left[i];
            i++;
        }
        else if(j != n_2){
            vec[k] = right[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
void merge_sort(std::deque<int> &A, size_type p, size_type r)
{
    int q;
    if(p < r - 1) {
        q = (p + r)/2;
        merge_sort(A, p, q);
        merge_sort(A, q + 1, r);
        merge(A, p, q, r);
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::deque<int> small_vec = {1, 6, 2, 10, 5, 2, 12, 6};
    std::deque<int> samp_vec = {2, 9, 482, 72, 42, 3, 4, 9, 8, 73, 8, 0, 98, 72, 473, 72, 3, 4, 9, 7, 6, 5, 6953, 583};
    print(small_vec);
    merge_sort(small_vec, 0, small_vec.size());
    print(small_vec);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output when I run the program:

```
left = 1 
right = 6 
left = 1 6 
right = 2 10 
left = 2 
right = 12 6 
left = 1 2 6 10 
right = 5 2 12 6 
1 2 5 2 6 10 12 6
```

Comment: check the book again, the `if`s in the loop don't look right.

Comment: @Comrade Karoly is right. The loops that "drain" the remaining elements from the "leftover" list has to come after the main loop that's doing the comparison -- not before.

Comment: I think the right vector just gets added to the main vector without begin sorted when it determines that the left vector is used up. I was under the impression that the method would prevent this.

Comment: You are seriously overcomplicating the logic for this. All you need to do is have a main loop that iterates until one of the list is exhausted. Afterwards, just transfer the remaining elements from whichever list is leftover.

Comment: @greatwolf. Thanks. My original code was pretty simple. I think my problem is exactly this, I am having trouble transferring the remaining elements. My edits just make it more convoluted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a lot of time and getting some valuable help on another post was able to get the algorithm to run correctly.

CORRECT CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
using size_type = std::deque<int>::size_type;
void print(std::deque<int> &v)
{
    for(const auto &ref:v)
        std::cout << ref << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
void print(int arr[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i != size; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
void merge(std::deque<int> &vec, size_type p, size_type q, size_type r)
{
    int n_1 = q - p + 1;
    int n_2 = r - q;
    std::deque<int> left, right;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i < n_1)
        left.push_back(vec[p + i++]);
    while(j < n_2)
        right.push_back(vec[j++ + q + 1]);
    i = 0; j = 0;
    //std::cout << "left = ";
    //print(left);
    //std::cout << "right = ";
    //print(right);
    for(auto k = p; k <= r; k++) {
        if((i < n_1 && left[i] <= right[j]) || j >= n_2) {
            vec[k] = left[i++];
        }
        else if(j < n_2){
            vec[k] = right[j++];
        }
    }
}
void merge_sort(std::deque<int> &A, size_type p, size_type r)
{
    int q;
    if(p < r) {
        q = (r + p) / 2;
        std::cout << "q = " << q << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "p = " << p << std::endl;
        merge_sort(A, p, q);
        merge_sort(A, q + 1, r);
        merge(A, p, q, r);
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::deque<int> small_vec = {10, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5, 3, 9, 7, 2, 8};
    std::deque<int> samp_vec = {2, 9, 482, 42, 3, 4, 9, 8, 73, 8, 0, 98, 72, 473, 72, 3, 4, 9, 7, 6, 5, 6953, 583};
    print(samp_vec);
    merge_sort(samp_vec, 0, samp_vec.size() - 1);
    print(samp_vec);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is here: `(i != n_1 && j != n_2) && left[i] <= right[j])` when `i != n_1` evaluates to false `vec[k] = right[j];` is executed - correct.

But if `i != n_1` evaluates to `true` and `j != n_2` to false i.e. `j = n_2` your program trys to do this `vec[k] = right[j];` again i.e. accesing over the bounds of your deque.

Rewrite your for loop as follows: 
`if (i<n_1 && (j>=n_2 || left[i] <= right[j])`
This loop works only due to C++'s short circuiting of the conditions i.e. when `j>=n_2` evaluates to `true`, `left[i] <= right[j]` is never checked again and you don't access the deque over bounds.

`left[i] <= right[j]` is being checked only if both `i<n_1` is true and `j>=n_2` false otherwise the 2nd branch is executed.

Comment: @Comrade check it now.

Comment: @Comrade also I would appreciate if you undo your question or at least post both versions of it: last one and new one because my answer relates totally to your first questions and has nothing to do with your edits.

Comment: Okay changed it back.

Comment: Yes it corrects the if condition. But the main problem with the code was that the left and right vectors weren't being filled correctly.